# I need to capture the data entered in a table as JSON in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I have an angular application to enter words in a table with two fields, I have to take all the ones you enter and compose it in JSON.

```html
 ngOnInit() {
    this.refactorForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'word_to_rename' : [null, Validators.required],
      'renowned_word' : [null, Validators.required]
     
    });
  }
```

this is the object that captures, I've seen something that should be done with array but I don't know how to do it. only the first row of the table captures me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made an example below that might be useful. I hope that will be useful.

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="refactorForm">
  <ng-container formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of refactorForm.get('items')['controls']; let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <input type="text" placeholder="word_to_rename" formControlName="word_to_rename">
      <input type="text" placeholder="renowned_word" formControlName="renowned_word">
      <button type="button" (click)="removeItem(i)">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
  <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <button type="button" (click)="addItem()">Add Row</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="save()">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-test',
  templateUrl: './form-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-test.component.css']
})
export class FormTestComponent implements OnInit {

  refactorForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.refactorForm = this.fb.group({
      items: this.fb.array([this.createItem()])
    });
  }

  createItem() {
    return this.fb.group({
      word_to_rename: ['', Validators.required],
      renowned_word: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  get refactorFormGroupItemsArray(): FormArray {
    return this.refactorForm.get('items') as FormArray;
  }

  addItem(): void {
    this.refactorFormGroupItemsArray.push(this.createItem());
  }

  removeItem(index) {
    this.refactorFormGroupItemsArray.removeAt(index);
  }

  save() {
    console.log(this.refactorForm.value.items);
  }

}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x3xinu

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, how would you create a function that erases only the last row?

Comment: You're welcome. You can replace the delete button with this code. `<button type="button" (click)="removeItem(i)" *ngIf="refactorForm.get('items')['controls'].length === i + 1">Remove</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Use Formbuilder array:

```
 ngOnInit() {
 this.refactorForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     'DETAILS': this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem() ])
    });
}


createItem(): FormGroup {

  return this.formBuilder.group({
    'word_to_rename' : ['', Validators.required],
    'renowned_word' : ['', Validators.required]
  });
}

addItem(): void {
  this.items.push(this.createItem());
}
```

Comment: already but my problem is that it only sends the first row, I need you to send all the ones you add, each row has two equal columns

Comment: I have edited the question, I have uploaded a photo of my table, in that table only take the first row, the ones you add do not take them.